# Como desvincular elementos de objetos?

Tags: javascript, jquery

Tenho a seguinte função

```
addPerson = function(id, name) {
    people[id] = name;

    console.log(people[id].parentNode); // Exibe corretamente
    console.log(name.parentNode); // Exibe corretamente

    name.parentNode.removeChild(name);

    console.log(people[id].parentNode); // Deixa de exibir
    console.log(name.parentNode); // Deixa de exibir

    if(!name.previousElementSibling) {
        $(name.parentNode).append(name);
    }else{
        name.previousElementSibling.insertAfter(name);
    }
};
```

--

O parâmetro `name` referência um elemento no `DOM`, quando a função é chamada `people[id]` recebe esse elemento, porém ao executar alguma alteração exemplo exclusão do elemento, a referência perde acesso aos métodos, exemplo o `parentNode`, tentei usar o `clone` do `J-query`, mas não funcionou.

Existe alguma forma de clonar o objeto, manter os métodos nativos e desvincular ele do elemento no `DOM`?

Comment: Hummm então em vez de vetor você poderia utilizar uma lista, acho que seria mais viável no seu caso.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Não precisas de clonar o elemento a não ser que precises de vários iguais.
Podes usar `var semPai = el.parentElement.removeChild(el);` e ficas com o elemento "na mão" fora do DOM.

```js
var div = document.querySelector('div');
var btn = div.firstElementChild;
btn.addEventListener('click', function() {
  console.log('Clicado!');
});

var semPai = btn.parentElement.removeChild(btn);
console.log(div.children.length); // vazio
console.log(semPai.parentNode); // sem pai!

btn.click();
```

```html
<div><button>Clica-me</button>
</div>
```

Se precisares saber a posicão inicial sugiro criares um objeto para guardar essa informação assim:

```js
var objs = [];

var div = document.querySelector('div');
var btn = div.firstElementChild;
btn.addEventListener('click', function() {
  console.log('Clicado!');
});

// guardar para mais tarde
objs.push({
  el: btn,
  previousSibling: btn.previousElementSibling || {},
  parent: btn.parentElement
});

btn.parentElement.removeChild(btn);
console.log(div.children.length); // 0 => vazio
console.log(btn.parentNode); // null => sem pai! está fora do DOM

// depois mais tarde...
objs[0].parent.insertBefore(objs[0].el, objs[0].previousSibling.nextSibling);
```

```html
<div><button>Clica-me</button>
</div>
```

Comment: Ainda não consegui, mesmo atribuindo diretamente a uma variável, estou usando uma biblioteca não sei se tem algo a ver.

Comment: @FelipeDuarte podes descrever mais o que a aplicação deve fazer? não te preocupes com a implementação, explica o que o precisas no programa

Comment: É um sistema de fazer e desfazer, estou usando essa biblioteca https://github.com/ArthurClemens/Javascript-Undo-Manager, ao acessar o método fazer preciso excluir o elemento (se existir) e recoloca-lo na mesma posição em que se encontrava

Comment: @FelipeDuarte ok. E como sabes onde estava? querias que o elemento guardasse isso mesmo estando fora do DOM, é isso?

Comment: É que estou fazendo testes, em definitivo tudo vai ser criado dinamicamente, por enquanto estou pegando direto no DOM. quando o método refazer for acionado, o elemento guardado no vetor, volte para o DOM na mesma posição, com previousElementSibling conseguiria coloca-lo na posição correta, porém o método some.

Comment: @FelipeDuarte juntei uma sugestão à resposta